# ¿Por qué ("a" > "A") retorna true?

Tags: javascript

También probé

```
("ab" > "ABC")
```

o

```
("ab" > "aB")
```

y retornan `true`.

Comment: [¿Cuáles son la reglas que determinan que un caracter alfabético es mayor, igual o menor que otro en javascript?](/q/233052)

Answer (score 2):

Cuando vemos la tabla ASCII. Cada letra, y símbolo tiene un valor. Por ejemplo, el valor de la vocal 'a' es 97, y el valor de la vocal 'A' en mayúscula es: 65. Por tal razón te puede retornar true.

Busca en el navegador Tabla ASCII, y verás cada uno de los valores de los símbolos y letras.